# ansible task with condition

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am using the below task in my play book and trying to set condition using "when" to trigger the task.

**the blow one is working**

```
ansible-playbook vdomqury.yml -e adom=In-Adom-01  -e FGT=FGVM04TM19001830  -e vdom= -vvv
```

**if i remove var vdom playbook stopped**

`ansible-playbook vdomqury.yml -e adom=In-Adom-01  -e FGT=FGVM04TM19001830  -vvv`

```
 tasks:
  - name: USE CUSTOM TYPE TO QUERY AVAILABLE SCRIPTS
    f_query:
      adom: "{{ adom }}"
      object: "custom"
      custom_endpoint: "/pm/config/adom/{{ adom }}/_package/status/{{ FGT }}/{{ vdom }}"
    register: results
    tags: ADDLAG
    when: vdom != "" 

  - name: USE CUSTOM TYPE TO QUERY AVAILABLE SCRIPTS
    f_query:
      adom: "{{ adom }}"
      object: "custom"
      custom_endpoint: "/pm/config/adom/{{ adom }}/_package/status/{{ FGT }}"
    register: results
    tags: ADDLAG
    when: vdom == "" or vdom is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the conditions to

```
when: vdom|default("")|length > 0
```

respectively

```
when: vdom|default("")|length == 0
```

Comment: thanks for the update, it worked as excepted. you are the man in this area:)

Answer (score 0):

You should check if vdom is defined before making a comparison on it, otherwise the interpreter will unsuccessfully try to fetch its value. This should work (can't check right now): `when: vdom is defined and vdom != ""`.